# Libre Office Calc - small sheet toolbar?

Tags: libreoffice, gtkrc

is there any possible way to enlarge this toolbar where sheets are listed (Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3, ...)? See the below screenshot:

[image]

In my case, these cards are so small that it's barely possible to click on it. Please help!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138623/sheet-name-font-size-on-libreoffice-calc-is-too-small the answer of 
user71720 works, but makes your slider grow as well. The file you are looking for is /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0

Comment: GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 16 seems to give a good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution without changing your theme :

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Find this line : `GtkScrollbar::sider-width`

Change it to the number you want , i change it to 25 .

Here my sheet font size :

[image]

Comment: i tried this and changed that value to 25, but then i tried to save it, and I got this error: ----"You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.----" Picture here: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2utm4ow.jpg

Comment: i fix the command , try now

Comment: welcome my friend

Comment: nice, and works - just one thing, I guess with the next update to the package containing the file, this change will be lost. I searched a while now, but didn't find anything (simple) to change it in a user-editable file...